# Memory leak iPhone and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem with big memory leaks when I use UIPageViewController. I have a view and I scroll it. I see that memory grows very fast.

I think that is the problem:

```
- (ViewControllerEvent *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    ViewControllerEvent *childViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[self isIPad]?@"Main_iPad":@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerEvent2"];

    childViewController.index = index;
    childViewController.event = [self.events objectAtIndex:index];
    return childViewController;

}
```

My class:

```
@interface ViewControllerEvent : UIViewController

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSDictionary *event;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *header;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *_scrollViewDesc;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *whiteBackground;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bootomMapImage;

@end
```

I use about 100 views in my pager.

Comment: Is this really an instance method? Shouldn't it be a class method?

Comment: You could reduce the memory usage by using a class method. See my answer below. An instance method would require an instance of the view controller that you are trying to vend for the page view controller.

Comment: I don't understand how to make this :(
I have two methods in my PageController:
like this:

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    
    NSUInteger index = [(ViewControllerEvent *)viewController index];
    
    index++;
    
    if (index == [self.events count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
    
}

Comment: it is from this toutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks are usually related to keeping strong references to some object which should have a weak reference, delegates for instance. Either that or you're keeping references to each child view controller, thereby growing the size of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an instance method to vend view controllers for the page view controller; use a class method instead.

```
+ (ViewControllerEvent *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    …

    return childViewController;
}
```